# Ubuntu boot menu options

Tags: recovery-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)

how to get the boot menu option where you can choose the recovery or the latest version of kernel?  it helped me in the past to boot into a recovery mode if things went wrong!