# ata2.00 failed to enable aa

Tags: boot, hard-drive, lenovo

I'm new to the world of Ubuntu. Installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS yesterday on a Lenovo Ideapad Y580 and till now I already recognized, that Lenovo is a bit infamous for this problem.

So when I boot up the laptop he gives me the error `ata2.00 failed to enable aa` and an error mask in brackets.

I surfed a bit around and it seems that the hard drive advertised something for it it doesn't have or isn't activated.

I'm always getting a black sreen after booting and I already saw this [threat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341502/how-to-fix-error-ata1-00-failed-to-enable-aa-0x1-error-mask), but I dont know how to use it or get the command working because when I boot in the shell to have a root command line it wont work.

Also I clearly don't want to give up the performance by deactivating `ncq`. I know I'm asking for a lot but can somebody please give me an instruction how to get the drivers set up to get the `fpdma` working or am I doomed? the numbers before the lines are always the same... [hhd information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBqgi.jpg) [moreinfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoSBv.jpg)

Comment: What was the error mask? From that we can determine the possible root cause.

Comment: i think it was 0x1 but im not near the laptop right now

Comment: yes it is the 0x1 error mask

Comment: would it lead to something if i format the hdd and before reinstall i let the drive be tested by the tool provided by seagate? but they also say on there website that there isnt a new firmware for this drive series...would that be wasted time?

Comment: @ColinIanKing dont now if the pics i put into the question helps any further, and sry for asking so much. it is ust the problem that the laptop is the one of my friend and i told him that i will make him work again and i would feel a bit bad for dont beeing able myself to get the laptop working again

Comment: @ColinIanKing i posted an answer on my question, dont know if you still care, but this way worked ot for myself... Thanks for your help an if you are still working on an kernel fix for kinds of this problems, pls keep on going, the community needs such persons like you, who can also give help in this special situations. even if you might just belong to the upper 3.0 %  :D

Answer (score 0):

So first of all i fixed my own problem ( a lenovo ideapad y580 ) by formatting the disk ( for information see the hdd information image in the question) and then doing a full erase with a seatools for dos bootable cd. Then i set the sata controller in the bios from "ahci" to "compatible" and reinstalled ubuntu 14.04 lts from the live cd. Now it mostly boots up fine, but i sometimes need to go into standby with the power button of the laptop after logging in, because the screen then sometimes still goes black. But after reactivating the laptop from standyby, ubuntu does work :) 
Hope that helps somebody too, but these solution might only be possible with the same hardware specs and as you can tell, it isnt the best solution at all...