# Lost access to sudo

Tags: sudo, hostname

```
sudo: unable to resolve host
```

I think I need to edit the `/etc/hosts` file to make an entry for 127.0.1.1 PC name.

But how can I do that if I can't access `sudo`? It seems to have gone since I updated to 13.10.

I have tried `nano`, which still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you boot into recovery mode then edit the hosts file with these steps:

1. Boot into recovery mode with steps from here: [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/176889)

   Steps 2 - 5 below are from the above question.
2. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> after your BIOS has passed, then choose:
   "Advanced options → something ending with *'(recovery mode)'*"
3. Choose the "Drop to root shell prompt" option
4. Remount the root partition as R/W with this command:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```
5. If you have separate partitions, execute this command to mount them:

   ```
   mount -a
   ```
6. Edit the `/etc/hosts` file with this command :

   ```
   nano /etc/hosts  # Replace `nano` with your favourite command line editor
   ```
7. Make the changes you want.
8. Press these keys to save and exit it: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>**;** <kbd>Y</kbd>**;** <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Note: If there's a `+` between two keys, press those at the same time. If there's a `;` between two key sequences, press the first sequence, then release it, then press the second.
9. Reboot:

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If you set a password on the root account, you can try :

```
su -
```

After putting the correct password in (if set) you should be "root" and free to change the files as needed.

Comment: This is unlikely to work as the root account is locked by default and so will not have a password set.  Best solution is to login to a recovery console then edit as root.

Comment: I agree if the password hasn't been set - as per my answer, however in the lucky situation that it has been - it works fine.  I always set a root password to avoid this type of issue.  This of course needs to be done before you have problems :)  From a working system, just sudo su - <CR>passwd and you're done.