# Ubuntu 14.04 sudo: unable to resolve host Cricketpunk

Tags: sudo, hostname

i am new to ubuntu and recently tried changing my hostname and have probably messed up something,and have trouble fixing it.

Whenever i give command like
    get sdu
      sudo apt-get install g++ (some command using sudo)

```
  sudo: unable to resolve host Cricketpunk
```

shows up,after 4 seconds of wait.After reading few questions,i tried changing something in /etc/hostname,but it says access denied when i try opening that file

**i Cannot boot into recovery mode due to soome bios fault**

I need help on how to achieve **sudo rights using live flash drive** containing ubuntu.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Have a good day :)

Comment: You will need to boot recovery mode and either revert the changes you made to the /etc/hostname file or make the /etc/hosts file consistent with it: see [Lost access to sudo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/368902/lost-access-to-sudo)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I can't seem to boot into recovery mode. can you outline some way I can do this process from a bootable pen drive?

Comment: You should just be able to mount the broken system's root from the live pen drive system and edit the file(s) from there: I don't have time to write a proper answer right now but will check back

Comment: Hi, in the live new pen drive, when I click on root folder, it says permission denied.