# How do I restore .bashrc to its default?

Tags: bashrc

I've been trying to install Android developer tools on Eclipse, and I followed the information in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qk9c-Ug2UI&list=PLQOohAn5nxx43fqFugU6dIwSQNbvXdgi5).

Like the video said, I added the following two lines of code to the `.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH=$(PATH):-/android-sdk/tools/
export PATH=$(PATH):-/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```

It seems, however, that this did not help me to install the Android files on Eclipse, as I am still having problems with that. What's more, it seems that I can't make any command in the terminal without getting a major error now! Every time I try to make a command in the terminal I get the following message:

> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in
>   the PATH environment variable.

Is there away to restore `.bashrc` to its default?

Comment: Root cause: The $(PATH) should in fact be $PATH

Comment: `$ nano .bashrc`

Answer (score 191, accepted):

**Idea:** There exist backup copies of `.bashrc`, `.profile` etc. in `/etc/skel/`. So one could replace a corrupt `.bashrc` simply by overwitting from there.

**Caution:**  if you replace the `.bashrc` file with a fresh one, it will remove any other modification(s) you have made to it. For example, one could add **aliases**, custom **function** or **PATH** in `.bashrc`. When you replace the file, all those modifications will be lost. Better you can keep a copy of your modified `.bashrc` before replacing it. Later, you can carefully extract the required part from it. To keep a backup copy of your modified `.bashrc` in your home directory with name `my_bashrc` use the following in a terminal,

```
/bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/my_bashrc
```

**Why `/bin/cp`:** In case if you have messed with your `$PATH` variable when changed `~/.bashrc` all the executable will be unavailable from your terminal and `cp` will not work anymore. So it is recommended to call `cp` with its full path as `/bin/cp` while you are trying to copy something with corrupt `~/.bashrc`.

Finally, use the following command in your terminal to replace the `~/.bashrc` with a fresh copy,

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

It will replace your corrupt `~/.bashrc` with a fresh one. After that, you need to source the `~/.bashrc` so that the change takes place immediately, write in the terminal,

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

or,

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or, if that does not work you can close the terminal and open it again.

Comment: Thank you for the response! For some reason I am still getting the error message

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: Command 'cp' is available in '/bin/cp'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cp: command not found

Comment: what is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: `:-/android-sdk/platform-tools`

Comment: where else did you put that `export` line except `.bashrc`?

Comment: I only put it in `.bashrc`

Comment: either remove those lines from your `.bashrc` or follow the above procedure. it will replace your .bashrc and end of problem

Comment: do not forget to `source /home/$USER/.bashrc` in either case.

Comment: And one thing you are missing from the beginning. the sign was tilde `~` not a hyphen. I forgot to mention before. `~` is equivalent to `/home/$USER` in shell

Comment: Thank you! Your help essentially worked; I just ended up having to manually more .bashrc to my home directory because the terminal wasn't working.

Comment: Note, this is essentially an overkill solution and will remove any other modification that you have done to the file.

Comment: what does the source command exactly do? where is it used?

Answer (score 14):

### If you can't get a working shell

#### Via the file browser

- Open the file browser, go to the home directory, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> so that hidden files are shown. Edit `.bashrc` as needed.
- Open the file browser, go to `/etc/skel`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> so that hidden files are shown. Copy `.bashrc` to your home folder to restore it to the default.

#### Via the run menu

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, type `gedit .bashrc`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Edit as needed.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, use the command `/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/` as given in [souravc's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/404428/158442) to restore it to the default.

#### Via the terminal

- Open the terminal, and ignore that you don't have a shell. Go to *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Profiles*:

  [image]
- Either create a new profile, or edit the current profile, to change the command:

  [image]

  Use either `/bin/bash --norc` or `/bin/bash --rcfile=/etc/skel/.bashrc`.
- Start a new tab (with the custom profile, if you created one). Use the working shell as needed.
- Delete the custom profile, or uncheck the custom command option if you edited the default profile, once you're done.

## If you have SSH

Run SSH with a custom command, which should help you bypass the `.bashrc`:

```
ssh -t <host> dash
```

The `dash` shell (aka `/bin/sh`) is minimal, but sufficient for restoring the `.bashrc`.

## If you can't get a GUI and don't have SSH

Boot into recovery mode ([How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/158442)), which will get you a root shell. Look in `/home` for your user's home directory.

Answer (score 9):

**Via the TTY**

You can enter the TTY by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd> where you have to login with your user-name and your password. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd> will bring you back to your GUI later.

Now copy the existing raw `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel` to your home directory by

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Maybe even bring the rest over if you're not sure if your `.profile` was changed too.

```
cp /etc/skel/.profile ~/
```

Now to get the `.bashrc` to have immediate effect you might want to source it with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If you did replace your `.profile` as well you need to reboot to make it take effect.

Comment: This solution works for me.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

I tried the above answers, but for some reason my `/etc/skel/` directory did not have the correct files in it.

I found a copy of the default `~/.bashrc` file on this [GitHub Gist by Mario Bonales](https://gist.github.com/marioBonales/1637696). The full script is copied here for completeness.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines in the history. See bash(1) for more options
# ... or force ignoredups and ignorespace
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Comment: If you must look online, then use the source: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/bash/trusty/view/head:/debian/skel.bashrc