# I messed the file bash.bashrc ubuntu 14.04

Tags: bashrc

Trying to install `java jre`, I messed up the file `bash.bashrc` on Ubuntu 14.04, by adding these two lines at the end :

```
export PATH= $PATH:usr/java/bin/ ; 
export JAVA_HOME= $JAVA_HOME:usr/java/bin/java/
```

Now I cannot do any command on terminal. When I open terminal it give me these errors:

```
bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:usr/java/bin/': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `:usr/java/bin/java/': not a valid identifier
bash: lesspipe: No such file or directory
bash: dircolors: No such file or directory
bash: ls: No such file or directory
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: delete the last two lines from that file.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the issue here is a specific syntax error (as has been answered already) and the answer in the "duplicate" is both overkill and irrelevant here since it is about `~/.bashrc` while this one is about `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Answer (score 7):

With:

```
export PATH= $PATH:usr/java/bin/ ; 
export JAVA_HOME= $JAVA_HOME:usr/java/bin/java/
```

`bash: export: ':usr/java/bin/java/': not a valid identifier`; Sure you left a space between `JAVA_HOME=` and `$JAVA_HOME:usr/java/bin/java/`, so `export` supposes that 
`$JAVA_HOME:usr/java/bin/java/` is a second variable. Same case for 1st line too.

```
export: usage: export [-fn] [name[=value] ...] or export -p
```

`...` means it does support/expect multiple variables with `name[=value]` format.

Remove spaces (after `=`) and semicolon `;` and add `/` before `usr/` (as it should be a full path):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/bin/
export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME:/usr/java/bin/java/
```

If still facing errors, take  l0b0's advice  ([Problem with installing Android developer files on Eclipse - messed up something with .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/problem-with-installing-android-developer-files-on-eclipse-messed-up-something)) to get new default `.bashrc` file, then try again adding those two lines.

Answer (score -1):

Edit you `.bashrc` file as follows:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin/
```

This assumes Java is installed in `/usr/java.`

Comment: There is a space still in the JAVA_HOME variable, it shouldn't be there.

Comment: Was is really necessary to downvote this comment several times?