# Can someone give me content of a fresh bash_profile text?

Tags: bashrc

Could someone give me the content of a fresh .bashrc ? I did not find it with Google.

Why ? Because I unfortunately ecrased it.

Comment: Title is not the same as the body. What do you need? http://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/restore-bashrc-to-its-default dupe against bashrc. Oh .bash_profile does not exist on my machine ;)

Comment: Do you meen this file /home/USER/.bashrc ? Ther are four .bashrc on my system

Comment: right ! /home/USER/.bashrc

Comment: Than use the link I posted (there is an original in /etc/skel ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a default `.bash_profile` but you can get a new copy of `.bashrc` from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/$USER/
```

If you meant `.profile`, that's also sitting in `/etc/skel`:

```
cp /etc/skel/.bash_profile /home/$USER/
```

Comment: But for bash_profile ?

Comment: That's what I'm saying, **there isn't a default `.bash_profile`**. It's not a thing (at least not on my system). We use `.profile`.

Comment: I thought it was already on my /home when i first installed an Ubuntu. Sorry. This fact solve by itself my issue. Also your command line.