# Cannot open gnome-terminal from Unity launcher or from side panel shortcut

Tags: command-line, unity, launcher, gnome-terminal

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 and everything seems to work fine, except that I cannot start gnome-terminal from Unity launcher or from a shortcut locked to the side panel.

However, gnome-terminal starts fine from Xterm or from right-click>Open Terminal. I can also run gnome-terminal by Alt-F2.

So, this seems to be a problem with Unity?

When pressing on gnome-terminal from Unity launcher or from a shortcut, the gnome-terminal icon just pulsates a bit, after which the shell terminates. I never see the shell itself, just its icon on the sidebar.

Searching for Terminal in Unity launcher, it finds gnome-terminal, but its name is "nlykkei@nlykkei-Ubuntu:~" and not the usual "Terminal".

Also, gnome-terminal doesn't show colors anymore, like green for an executable, etc.

Can someone guide me on how to restore my Unity Terminal? I've already spent 2-3 hours on Google, attempting to solve the problem by configuring locale settings.

Comment: This probably won' t solve the colors, but will re- enable the Unity icopn: most likely, you have a weird and error-some copy of the global .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` .  That will cause the weird mention in Dash. As a start, remove the file locally, log out and back in. When started from cli, the terminal surpasses the (any) .desktop file.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The shell can be launched from Unity again. Do you have any idea on how to restore colors?

Comment: You could see what happens if you rename `~/.bashrc`, (rename back if it doesn' t work)?

Comment: There is no ~/.bashrc. It is not restored by opening gnome-terminal. How can I restore it?

Comment: Run in terminal: `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`, then relaunch the terminal (nice answer found here: http://askubuntu.com/a/404428/72216)

Comment: Thanks dude! My terminal works again!!! I've really no idea what caused this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although we only can guess what has happened, two things seem not in order:

1. The fact that in Dash, you get `nlykkei@nlykkei-Ubuntu:~`, when looking for the terminal, confirms the fact that you must have a local (error-some) copy of the `gnome-terminal.desktop` -file. This also explains why it *does* run from cli in `xterm`; the `.desktop` file is surpassed then.
2. The fact that you lost colors in the terminal points to the fact that there is something wrong in your `~/.bashrc` -file.

#### To solve

1. Remove any local copy of a `.desktop` file, calling `gnome-terminal` (to be found in `~/.local/share/applications`). The Unity Launcher and Dash will then use the global one again.
2. Restore the original `~/.bashrc` file by running the command:

   ```
    cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
   ```

Subsequently log out and back in, and it should be fixed.