# cannot access the ~/.bashrc again

Tags: bash, bashrc

After I installed the conda, I still cannot call the conda. And I follow the below steps to add the path.

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
export PATH= "/home/howard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
sudo gedit /etc/profile
export PATH="/home/howard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"

source /etc/profile
```

However, the situation even worst. I cannot call conda and nvcc. **"not found"**
Also, when I restart the terminal, it say

```
bash: 
export: /home/username/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin':
 not a valid identifier
```

When I wanna get back to `~/.bashrc` to delete the export path, by using `sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`
It tells bash: `sudo: No such file or directory`

Can anyone help?

Comment: `sudo` is going to have a different definition of `~` compared to your ordinary user.  try issuing the command with the full path the `.bashrc` file, e.g. `sudo gedit /home/myusername/.bashrc`  but of course you'll need to change that path to match your actual path.

Comment: sudo gedit /home/user1/.bashrc
bash: home: No such file or directory
user1@user1-PC:~$ ls
bash: ls: No such file or directory

Comment: I don't know the file structure on your machine.  `/home` may not be correct either.  As ordinary user, do: `cd ~ ` then do `pwd`.  Then paste that output into your question.

Comment: After cd ~  then do pwd
/home/user1
However, when I use ls to check the content, bash: ls: No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, as your ordinary user, type `cd ~` then hit the enter key.  After hitting the enter key, type `pwd`, then hit the enter key again.  After hitting the enter key the second time, observe what is printed out at that point in your console, and copy and paste that here.

Comment: OK if your home directory is `/home/user1` then do `ls -a`.  Is there a file called `.bashrc` listed?

Comment: I copy the pwd return " /home/user1 " in the sudo gedit /home/user1/.bashrc. And the output is bash: sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: After I do ls -a, it return bash: ls: No such file or directory
I am doubt about whether it is related to "" bash: export: `/home/username/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/usr/local/cuda-11.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin': not a valid identifier""

Comment: I notice that I keep staying in user1@user1-PC:~$ "~".
Is that the reason Is return not founded.

Comment: I'm not able to diagnose this.  If bash is saying it cannot find "ls" that is pretty bad.

Comment: You need to remove the space after the `=` in `export PATH= "/home/howard/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`. Because you messed up `PATH` you will need to call programs with their full paths like `/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/sudo gedit ~/.bashrc`. In future DON'T use `sudo` to edit files in `~` (but you will probably need to do so now because they have likely become owned by `root`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default)