# My terminal loads with junk text. How can I remove this?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu

```
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AGENT_PID="1411"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x USER="nishan"
declare -x VTE_VERSION="6003"
declare -x WINDOWID="71303171"
declare -x XAUTHORITY="/home/nishan/.Xauthority"
declare -x XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="XFCE"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share"
declare -x XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/lightdm-data/nishan"
declare -x XDG_MENU_PREFIX="xfce-"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SEAT="seat0"
declare -x XDG_SEAT_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="xubuntu"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_ID="c2"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_PATH="/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="x11"
declare -x XDG_VTNR="7"
```

I am using Xubuntu 20.04 LTS version, freshly installed and updated. Since a recent update, every time I open terminal this text appears inside. I have to clear it using the `clear` command. I want to get rid of this as it's very annoying.

Comment: Does this happen when you open a new terminal? Please [edit] your question and add the content of your `~/.bashrc` file.

Comment: ... possibly a malformed `export` command

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of: `grep -n declare ~/.bashrc ~/.profile`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from [How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default)

Make a copy of current bashrc file

```
/bin/cp ~/.bashrc ~/my_bashrc
```

Copy system default bashrc

```
/bin/cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/
```

Tell system to use copied bashrc file immediately

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: I suggest you to compare the old and the new `.bashrc` file to understand if the differences may be the cause of the issue you had.