# Terminal doesn't have color and some commands stopped working

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Recently, my terminal stopped showing color, so all text is white, and also some commands like `l` don't work anymore.
I've tried commands like `sudo apt-get reinstall gnome-terminal`, but then I realised Guake had the same effect. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Sounds like you’ve done something to your bash profile 

Comment: Some possibilities (1) your terminals are using some other shell instead of bash (2) the bash shell in your terminals is no longer sourcing your ~/.bashrc file (3) you modified your ~/.bashrc file so it is no longer applying color settings or defining the `l` alias.

Comment: @steeldriver, I can't find ~/.bashrc. Maybe I've deleted that file accidentally?

Comment: If you're checking with a file manager, remember to turn on "Show hidden files". OTOH if you really have deleted it, that would explain why the shell is no longer sourcing it ;) You can obtain a copy of the default ~/.bashrc from the /etc/skel directory ex. `cp -i /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/`

Comment: I know, @steeldriver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an answer, thanks @steeldriver!
The fix was posted on [How do I restore .bashrc to its default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404424/how-do-i-restore-bashrc-to-its-default) and the answer is to just copy /etc/skel/.bashrc to ~

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the standard bash shell. Use this to confirm.

```
echo "$SHELL"
```

Next, check that you have a bash profile:

```
ls ~/.bashrc
```

If this does not return anything, then you have nuked your profile. So lets get you a clean profile. This will give you a standard bash profile, but if you managed to remove .bashrc, you would need to check what else you have inadvertently destroyed

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~
```

Then do the spell below to get the bash profile activated :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

This file has a section between lines 38 and 89 that sets up the terminal colours. You can investigate this, but a detailed explanation is beyond a simple answer. Most people (most Unix experts!) leave this alone.