# .profile edit in terminal log loop

Tags: command-line, 13.10, login-screen

While following a guide to install unity so I can program for ouya it asked me to add a line into my .profile. After I did that and restarted I am no stuck at the login screen.
I'm not sure how to fix this or how to remove the line of code I added in.
Can any tell me how I can remove this line from the terminal?
At the log in screen I can hit ctrl alt f3 and log in to my account but when I switch back to the GUI it just keeps looping please help
I don't want to have to format my hard drive.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Can you boot into the recovery-mode? You should be able to change the line back from there. http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode

Answer (score 0):

If you can login in the third virtual console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - also called tty1) this is a good thing because you can restore the file `.profile` to its default content only by running the following command in your virtual console:

```
cp /home/$USER/.profile /home/$USER/.profile.old
cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/$USER
```

Comment: I'd make a backup 1st and no need for user_name ;)