# system freezes shortly after sign-in on a newly installed 14.04 ubuntu desktop

Tags: 14.04, system

I am able to move the mouse cursor around for a bit after sign-in, the system soon freezes - keyboard or mouse does not work. The activity light at front of computer flashes. The only way to bring the system down is by unplugging the power cord.

Comment: I had similar problem earlier, see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/150377/178235) to boot into Terminal Recovery Mode, then see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting) to **fsck** your system, if that worked, tell me so I can convert it to an answer

Comment: Let me guess, this happened after unexpected shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

hi thank you all for pointing me to a few places.

The shut downs were not unexpected, because I had to pull the power plug  many times as nothing seemed  to work, not the PC's power switch,  the keyboard or the mouse.

I did try the Alt-Sys Req, R,E,I,S,U,B route, it didn't do a thing for me, keyboard seemed to have locked, pulled the power cord again.

I also tried booting into recovery mode. what I saw on the monitor was 'Grub loading ...', then it went away and the monitor became blank. But I did find out Grub was on device /dev/sda1.

As to the fsck tool to check out the integrity of the file system, the procedure is way beyond my level of comprehension.

Soon as I bought up an application (such as Firefox web browser, or Ubuntu Application centre), seconds later the cursor /mouse/keyboard stopped working. But I did manage to get a terminal
session and completed sudo apt-get update. The terminal session seemed last a bit longer but eventually the same situation happened.

I also posted another question regarding a problem trying to install Lubuntu 15.04 on the same desktop PC, and I mentioned that I was running Ubuntu 12.04 before prior to trying to 
upgrade it to either Ubuntu 14.04 or Lubuntu 15.04. Some bright idea!

Anything else I can try?