# Ubuntu stops loading with "starting version 219" on screen after switching to propriety driver

Tags: drivers

I just switched my graphics to use the propriety driver instead and after reboot it stop at >starting version 219".

Nothing works. I cannot get terminal by Ctrl+Alt+F1 or anything else.

If I press the power button it shows the Ubuntu logo and powers off.

How can I get back to the generic driver?

Comment: What brand of GPU ? Nvidia ?

Comment: ATI HD5450 graphics card. A friend told me never to use the propriety drivers, but I decided to check if I get better graphics, multiple screen management etc. after reading this article [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/10/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-15-10)

Comment: Boot to recovery https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode and see http://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers

Comment: You SHOULD use a prop driver. You can use this guide for installing the correct driver http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx

Comment: Ok I tried all the advanced options, but got stuck on error about "running in low graphics mode". I rebooted about  times and when at the same screen got to the terminal and the machine booted the the login screen. After login it just kicked me out again without any errors. I tried my other desktops and managed to login LXDE. Now to find how to change back from the propriety driver in LXDE. Ok I found it and switching back to the open source driver. Ok after rebooting back to the same 219 error.

Comment: The second link I gave you, enter the commands in a terminal or see the answer below by @e.lopez, it is the same information..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this post to get into recovery mode:

[How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)

In essence:

> - Switch on your computer.
> - Wait until the BIOS has finished loading, or has almost finished. (During this time you will probably see a logo of your computer
>     manufacturer.)
> - Quickly press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the GNU GRUB menu. (If you see the Ubuntu logo, you've missed the point where
>     you can enter the GRUB menu.) **
> - Select the line which starts with "Advanced options". *
> - Select the line ending with "(recovery mode)"

And then remove all ATI propietary drivers following this other post:

[How do I remove the proprietary ATI drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68306/how-do-i-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers)

> - Try to completely remove your ATI drivers from your system:

```
sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"
```

> - Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

> - Reinstall xorg completely

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

> - Re-configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

> - Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Thank I`m were busy doing this. Just had to get the PC internet first in terminal to be able to use apt-get etc. And yes thank you I`m back up and running.

Comment: @NazeemJansen If this is the correct answer please press the check mark on the left, this thanks the user for the answer and helps other find the information easier.

Comment: Thanks. I will be looking at using the prop drivers as mentioned now that I know how the fix this problem, but on the page [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-proprietary-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx) I do not see drivers for 15.10 or should I just use the method as with 14.04?

Comment: @NazeemJansen Yes follow the 14.04 / 14.10 , there seems to only be one option for Ubuntu on that card anyway (Ubuntu x86_64) so it should be fine.