# how to revert changes on /etc/environment, which prevent a login

Tags: environment-variables

I have just added this line "export PATH=/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin:$PATH" to my /etc/environment file.

I tried to restart Ubuntu 14.04 and now I cannot log in with my user/pw in the OS.

could someone please explain to me what have I done and how could I repair it¿?

Please help!

Comment: Once you have fixed the mistake, you may want to study [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) about how to do it instead. I would have used a `*.sh` file in the `/etc/profile.d` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your system, when starting press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to reach the grub bootmenu.

Start the [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode), open a root shell and revert the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar while configuring Texstudio to find arara in Texlive.
Your system is most likely stuck in a login loop. But don't follow [this highly upvoted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/707756) to this [login loop question](https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/707756). Instead, do what I say below:

- Ctrl+ Alt_+F3 and login to the session.
  [image: Ctrl+ Alt_+F3 output]
- Check if you can run any shell command like `ls`. If not then that's the problem.
- Type /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/vim /etc/environment
- Use your knowledge of vim to delete the line that you added.
- You can use any other non-GUI editor if you know the path to that editor's executable.
- Save the file ':wq  for vim'
- type  Poweroff
- You would get some command suggestion like`/sbin/poweroff`
- Use it to power off or you can simply pull the plug.
- Restart and you are done.

Both of us modified /etc/environment to add some environment variables and we made a mistake. Then we used an editor to rectify that mistake by deleting whatever we added. After shutting down and restarting the computer was able to use the correct configurations. Hence, everything proceeded smoothly and things got fixed.

The credit goes to the comments by [siddharthart](https://askubuntu.com/users/52448/siddharthart) and [jbbarquero](https://askubuntu.com/users/279458/jbbarquero) to [this highly upvoted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/223634/707756). Also, [xpioneer](https://askubuntu.com/users/876745/xpioneer) comment in the [login loop question](https://askubuntu.com/q/223501/707756) reconfirmed what I had determined above.