# Too many error messages!

Tags: apt

I am in need of a lot of help right now.

Recently I had tried getting Kali Tools and I had downloaded a Kali Tools repositories and now it's not letting me do anything.

I didn't know that by downloading the repositories for Kali Tools would mess up Ubuntu. I'm getting different errors.

Here you will be able to see a picture of the errors to see if you guy/girls can help me.

[image]

I have been trying to open Software & Updates but it doesn't work. Everything that comes preinstalled into Ubuntu doesn't open. It only loads then closes. So that's something bad because I don't know another way of deactivating repositories.

Comment: You didn't know that installing software from _another operating system_ would mess up Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you install Kali tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are now a *lot* of underlying issues with your installation of Ubuntu.

Essentially, you managed to replace all the system configurations and definitions you had with those that Kali Linux provides.

You can see this in your screenshot -- your system has now named itself `Kali 2016.1`, which is the absolute least of your worries. Due to how Kali Linux operates and what it does, it has replaced a lot of config files with its own versions.

The only way to restore your working Ubuntu installation is to backup any important data from your `/home` folder and re-install Ubuntu. There is very little you can do to patch what you've done.

In the future, don't import PPAs from dissimilar OSes, unless you know *exactly* what you're doing and that there's no other way to accomplish what you want.

---

**Edit on request of OP:**

If you cannot recover your files from the graphical interface for whatever reason, you can use [Recovery Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode).

1. Follow the instructions above to drop yourself into a root shell.
2. Insert your external hard drive (or large flash drive) into a free USB port.
3. Use the `lsblk` command to find the hard drive you just plugged in. Make note of the device identifier (something like `/dev/sdc1`).
4. Type `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to mount your drive.
5. `cd` to your home directory (you'll have to manually specify your username as `~` doesn't work).
6. Use `cp` to copy any important files over to `/mnt`. For example: `cp -R Documents/ /mnt`
7. After you've finished your important files (it's not a good idea to keep `.local` configs, and the like), type `umount /mnt` and wait for the prompt to return. Unplug your drive.
8. Reboot your computer using `reboot`, and re-install Ubuntu using a spare flash drive.

Comment: Hey Whaaaaaat, I know its of what you are saying but where do I go to restart ubuntu and still have my files backedup?

Comment: @Apjunior770 Grab a flash drive and boot into Ubuntu. From there, copy any and all important files from your home folder onto it. When you're done, get another thumb drive and burn the Ubuntu Install ISO onto it. Guides for both of these things are available on this site. If you can't copy your files graphically, you can always use Recovery mode to get in. However, this is more involved. If you want, I can edit my post with info for how to do a recovery mode backup.

Comment: That would be amazing if you could edit your post on how to do a recovery mode :D thank you so much for the help and and I give 100 coffees.

Comment: @Apjunior770 Post has been updated with some basic instructions. If you want more help or need me to clarify, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Open a console (terminal) and type `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and remove all entries from Kali. Then run `sudo apt update`.

To get rid of the error messages run `sudo rm /var/crash/*`