# Unable to log in to my system

Tags: 14.04, chown

I can no longer log in to my system after running this command :

```
sudo chown -R &USER: $HOME
```

as ROOT because I couldn't access  a certain file.

Now I can't log in again.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the Caps Lock? :-)

Comment: Nope,  it's not caps lock issue, if it was, it was shown me invalid credentials.

Comment: So, what error or message do you get and at what stage?

Comment: Once I input my credentials, the system returns the login screen again.  Do you know of the command I stated above?

Comment: You have made the non-existent user &USER the owner of your home directory. You just need to `chown` it back. Please either boot in recovery (enable networking and start a root shell) or with a live usb/Cd (mount your root partition and `/home` if it is on another partition) and run the command `sudo chown -R username: /home/username` **where `username` is your username**. If you don't know how to do these things, please take a look at questions such as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) for guidance or comment and I or someone else will help you

Comment: Thank you all for your help. @Zanna I'm forever grateful. Problem solved.

Comment: awesome :D maybe you could post an answer to your question below with all the steps you did to help others in future :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I solved my problem following [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) recommendation.

1. I booted into **Recovery mode** by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key when restarting. When the **GRUB menu** shows, I selected the option that started with **Advanced Option** which shows options like `Ubuntu GNU/Linux, with Linux 3.8.0-26-generic (recovery mode)`. I chose the first option with recovery mode and then selected **Enable networking**.
2. I chose **root shell prompt** after (1) and ran the command `sudo chown -R username: /home/username` **where username is my username**. After the process finished running, I exited the shell and restarted my system.

And Voila! I was able to log in again with no files affected, everything was intact. :)