# Will an Ubuntu upgrade restore my rights privileges?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, do-release-upgrade, chown

I couldn't log in to my system because of a certain command I ran,  I was able to access my system shell and saw the option for upgrade. Will the upgrade restore my rights privileges so that I can log in to my system again?  Please your help is highly  appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same problem you wrote about [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861237/unable-to-log-in-to-my-system), then no. The update will update packages in system directories, not content in $HOME.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought that upgrading and re-installing are almost the same.

Comment: Well, update only updates packages that have newer versions. Reinstall overwrites all packages. But none of them updates access-rights on files in /home .. a reinstall might overwrite /home if you don't take care. Just do what @Zanna wrote in the other question.