# Ubuntu 14.04 Login Loop problem after appending .profile file in home folder

Tags: 14.04, login, tty, .profile

Ubuntu 14.04 get stuck when trying to login my desktop. The screen goes black and soon after that the login screen bounce back.

Actually i added a line in /.profile file in last boot-up `export PATH= .:$PATH` 
and during next boot, it started to enter in loop.

login into tty1 showing

```
-bash: export: '.:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/db/bin:/home/mohammad/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/mohammad/android-sdk-linux/tools' : not a valid identifier
```

entering any command in tty1 showing

```
-bash:<command name> : NO such file or directory
```

Comment: just boot in recovery mode and do `cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/username/.profile` **where `username` is your username**

Comment: yes so `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: @Zanna, this didn't help

Comment: @Zanna actually the whole process didn't help

Comment: you replaced `username` with your actual username in the command and rebooted right? and you still get the same error?

Comment: @Zanna  yeah  i used following command  `mount -o remount,rw /` and followed by `cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/mohammad/.profile` . after this the `.profile` file is changed but unable to boot.

Comment: o.O unable to boot or still got login loop?

Comment: @Zanna still got in login loop

Comment: hmm OK... I think what I would try is to temporarily modify `~/.profile` to export the default PATH (in recovery again, add to the end of the file `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`) but I am uncertain if something else may have got broken by your original action that I don't understand...

Comment: @Zanna, still didn't. it is necessary to have `,bashrc` file at both `home/mohammad` and  `/etc` folder

Comment: sorry I am confused, are you asking me or telling me? What are you doing to `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: @Zanna, i said it is still in loop

Comment: @Zanna, i asked, it is necessary to have `.bashrc` file  in `/etc` and in '`home/mohammad` folder

Comment: yes your system needs the systemwide bashrc `/etc/bash.bashrc` and your local bashrc `~/.bashrc`. Why do you ask?

Comment: @Zanna `~/.bashrc` is also empty

Comment: In which case, do `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /home/mohammad/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you wanted to be able to run commands in your current working directory without typing the prepending `./`? Oh well, this is still fixable.

You've only messed up your own user profile, so we can use the root account to repair this damage. First off, you're going to want to boot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) on your system. From there, select the option that says `root`, which will drop you into a usable terminal.

From there, you want to `cd` to your user's home folder (`/home/<your username>`, the `~` shortcut will not work here). From there, edit your `.profile` file with something like `nano` or `vi`. Delete the line containing:

```
export PATH= .:$PATH
```

Be sure to also check `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile` and similar files just to be sure. Remove the same line there (if they exist).

---

If you do want to try this again, be careful to not include spaces in the profile, and be sure to add the `.` to the end, like so:

```
export PATH="$PATH":.
```

Comment: `nano .profile` creates a new file instead of opening old one

Comment: @TheBlueMagician Did you actually `cd` to your home folder first?

Comment: yeah, i cd to home directory `root@blue:/home/mohammad# nano .profile`

Comment: using vi when i tried to open, it showig `e303 unable to open swap file for ".profile", recovery impossible`

Comment: @TheBlueMagician Are you sure it was in just `.profile` and not something like `.bash_profile`? Does `ll | grep profile` show the file?

Comment: `ll | grep grep profile` does not show any file. i think it is missing

Comment: Did you mean to type `grep` twice?

Comment: no sorry only with single `grep`

Comment: i used this for new copy 'cp /etc/skel/.profile /home/username/.profile` but original problem still persist