# sudo is deleted

Tags: software-installation, sudo

How can I install the `sudo` package?

```
$ apt-get install sudo
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Comment: I can't believe that this is actually possible XD. Note to self: DONT DELETE SUDO! ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you've actually deleted the `sudo` command, you can reinstall the package that provides it by running:

```bash
pkexec apt-get update
pkexec apt-get --reinstall install sudo
```

This works because most Ubuntu systems have two separate ways that let administrators perform actions as root, [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) and [Polkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit). When sudo is broken, Polkit is usually still intact.

You must be logged in as an administrator to do this, of course. If you're using an account who was allowed to use `sudo` (back when `sudo` existed on the system), that should work fine.

On a minimal system or Ubuntu server system, Polkit may be unavailable, and with  some configurations you will not be able to run the `pkexec` command over an SSH session.

---

You [have indicated](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34944295#34944295) that `pkexec`, while not deleted like `sudo`, is also broken. Specifically, on your system it has the wrong ownership or permissions. It is supposed to be [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) root, but it is not, and therefore it cannot be used.

[It would be useful to know](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34944296#34944296) how `/usr/bin/sudo` was deleted, and how `/usr/bin/pkexec`'s permissions (or ownership) got changed. These are two, seemingly separate breaking changes to your system. If a recursive (`-R`) `chown` or `chmod` has been performed on `/`, `/usr`, or `/usr/bin`, that would explain how `pkexec`'s permissions were changed, and an appropriate fix would do more than just changing them back for that one executable.

With that said, if the only two things wrong with your system are that `sudo` is missing and `pkexec` has wrong permissions or ownership, [this is still easily fixed](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34944300#34944300), though you will have to reboot into recovery mode or chroot in from a live environment. I suggest recovery mode.

1. [Boot in recovery mode.](https://askubuntu.com/a/150377)
2. Remount `/` readwrite by running: `mount -o remount,rw /`
3. Ensure `pkexec` has correct ownership: `chown root:root /usr/bin/pkexec`
4. Fix `pkexec`'s permissions: `chmod 4755 /usr/bin/pkexec`
5. Boot into your system (`exit` and follow the prompts), or reboot with `reboot`.
6. Follow the above instructions for reinstalling the `sudo` package by running `apt-get` with `pkexec`.

This has the advantage of working whether or not any Internet connection is available in recovery mode, without involving downloading `.deb` files and manually installing them. With `--reinstall`, `apt-get` will replace all the package files for `sudo`, which can fix additional problems. Plus, this also fixes your broken `pkexec`.

However, this is not the only approach. In particular, the method given in [San Lin Naing's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/875002/22949) should work, too. The main difference is that, in the method given here, no package management operations are carried out in the chroot, which is only used to repair `pkexec` so it can then be used to manage packages when booted normally.

Comment: it's give me error:pkexec must be setuid root

Comment: okey my sudo file  is deleted? when i run pkexec apt-get update command it gives me must be setuid root error.i can not install anything and when i try to reinstall sudo it gives error like  Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: yes i acidentlly deleted the sudo file. the output of  ls -l /usr/bin/sudo is cannot access '/usr/bin/sudo': No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52251/discussion-between-eliah-kagan-and-kaliya-mitesh).

Answer (score 2):

> yes i acidentlly deleted the sudo file. the output of ls -l /usr/bin/sudo is cannot access '/usr/bin/sudo': No such file or directory

Just a thought:

You still have the media (DVD / USB stick) from which you installed Ubuntu to your system?

1. Boot from it and mount your PC's system partition.
2. Copy  `/usr/bin/sudo` from the live system to the mounted partition.
3. Check that the file's owner and permissions are the same.
4. Reboot to your system.

Answer (score 2):

You need `root` permission to install any software. But, you had deleted the `sudo` package.

If you have access as a `root`, you may be able to install `sudo` again.

Reference to this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/92558/640587).

Try to start with `bash mode` with `root` user.

1. Reboot your system.
2. Long press `Shift` key or `Esc` key.
3. Choose `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.
4. Choose `Ubuntu, with Linux x.x.x-xx-generic (recovery mode)`.
5. Choose `root    Drop to root shell prompt`
6. Type `mount -o rw,remount /` command to gain read write access.
7. Type `apt install sudo`. Follow on screen instructions.

If installation finished, It is done!

If **not**, this may need network connection.

Lets reboot your system to normal boot and download required files.
If so, `Ctrl + D` will go menu page again and choose `resume`. This will go to normal boot.

You may need to install sudo offline. This may be another research. [Here](https://www.sudo.ws/download.html#binary) you can find `.deb` package. You can download with your OS version. Download your file that is `sudo_1.8.19-3_xxxx.deb`. And then remember your download `file path`.

Reboot your system in `bash mode (recovery mode)` again and follow 1-6 steps.

And then `dpkg -i *file_path/sudo_1.8.19-3_xxxx.deb`. This will install `sudo`. Finished! `Ctrl + D` and choose `resume` to normal boot.

Done!

Answer (score 0):

You can build `sudo` from source

```
mkdir sudo-src
cd sudo-src
apt-get source sudo
cd sudo-x.y.z
./configure --prefix=$HOME
make
make install
```

Comment: A non-root user who has no way to perform actions as root has no way to install `sudo` in such a way that it will be able to let users to run commands as other users (such as root). Specifically, the `sudo` executable must be [setuid root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), and non-root users cannot change a file's ownership to root. It is very good that this will not work -- if it did, then anyone with an account could escalate their own privileges to root and run arbitrary code by installing their own version of `sudo`! But unfortunately this means the method given here won't help.

Comment: This is great idea!  Where did you get the 'source'?  Have you tried this and it was successful?  I'm curious how `make install` works here when the OP doesn't have access to escalation as part of their question.

Comment: `sudo` is an [open source project](http://www.sudo.ws). It's source is available on project's site and likely through your distribution's package manager as source package.

Comment: @earthmeLon There are several ways to get the source, and if source repos are enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, the way here will successfully retrieve it. If `build-essential` is installed, it can even be built this way. **But you can never install a *working* `sudo` using this method.** A non-root user simply does not have the capability to cause `sudo` or its supporting files to be owned by the root user, and without that, `sudo` cannot do anything. [Try it and see: the `make install` step fails with an "Operation not permitted" error running `chown`.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23849727/)

Comment: Yes, I was encouraging @GAD3R to come to that conclusion.