# ctrl+alt+f1 cause login loop due to my changes on ~/.profile

Tags: login

I changed my ~/.profile and added few lines to make it run when i login to my user account :

```
google-chrome # to start chrome
code # to start vs code
exit 0
```

but since then i can't login
i tried to use guest session to login with ctrl+alt+f1 but whenever i type my username and password i get logged in then it asks me to log in again, if I can undo my changes to that file I think I will be able to log in back normally but every solution i found depends on the ctrl+alt+f1-f6 solution which won't work for me...

Comment: You could probably use recovery mode to fix this. See [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/q/150367/301745)

Comment: BTW, it's the `exit 0` that's the main problem. It signs you out as soon as it runs. Also, GUI programs (i.e. Chrome and VS Code) should be set up in Startup Applications, not ~/.profile.

Comment: I couldn't reach the GRUB I tried to hold shift and tried esc but both didn't work, my labtop is hp i remember getting into it on lenovo, i don't know what is the wrong thing I'm doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot from Ubuntu install CD or USB. Your hard drive should automount in a subdirectory in /media/ubuntu/harddrive_blockdevice_number/ which will be the root directory. Then edit the profile from that directory:

sudo vi home/username/.profile

Comment: i couldn't get to the file but i used USB to reinstall ubuntu again