# Boot Ubuntu in basic text only mode

Tags: 16.04, boot, grub2

I run Ubuntu 16 on VMWare machine. After removing X11 configuration files I got this message during startup:

```
The system is running in low-graphics mode

Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected
correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.
```

Mouse and keyboard don't work after displaying this message. How can I boot in a very basic mode and get a console? <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> etc to select text console doesn't work.

This is not duplicate, since I'm asking not about fixing displayed error, but how to get to console mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to boot in recovery mode: [How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)

Or you can also follow this guide:
[How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Hope it helps, good luck!