# How can I login to Ubuntu again

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to install the Geant4.10.04.p02 on Ubuntu 18.04 and when I switch the environment-variables using the command `sudo vi /etc/profile.d/geant4.sh` and restart Ubuntu gives an error. 
How can I login to Ubuntu again?

[image]

Comment: Those are warnings, not fatal errors, and basically they shouldn't prevent you from logging in. OTOH, there should be a clickable OK button, but due to the large number of failures it seems to not be visible.,.

Comment: Yes thank you. Now I can access the desktop. Did you mean that the changes that I made for the Geant4 environment-variables are correct

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. I mean that a failure at login to read that file should generate warnings, but shouldn't prevent you from logging in. I don't know what the file looks like now, but the one which caused the above message was certainly not correct.

Comment: OK . I am sorry for the misunderstanding. Thank you again, the file is not currently working and I am working to fix it. Greetings to you

Answer (score 1):

Edit: looking at the error message again, it seems like you specified relative paths where absolute paths were expected, so deleting may be overkill.

The error message clearly states that `geant4.sh` is trying to `cd` to directories that don't exist. Thus, the X session is not started. To be able to use the desktop environment again, fix, move or delete `geant4.sh`:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to switch to tty4. Login with your username and password. Then run the following command to edit the file:

```
sudo vi /etc/profile.d/geant4.sh
```

Or, to remove it:

```
sudo rm /etc/profile.d/geant4.sh
```

Alternative 1: You can boot Ubuntu in [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/a/150377/354663) and access the file from a root shell.

Alternative 2: You can boot a live system and access the file from there.

Comment: Thank you
I put my username and password correctly but ask me login incorrect

Comment: It's possible that there is a different keyboard layout. Try entering your password on the login prompt (where you see the characters you typed) and see if the correct characters are produced.