# Ubuntu failed to boot: "Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi" corrupted

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I recently started using Linux Ubuntu (18.04.1). After recent update I restarted my laptop to switch for Windows. The next day when I tried to launch Ubuntu, instead regular purple dual boot menu I got this:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt, buffersize 1000
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
System BootOrder not found.             
Initializing defaults
Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi\ - Volume Corrupt
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
StartImage failed: 10
```

And no button works. The main reason I ran here to start this thread is because I can not access Ubuntu recovery mode by any possible way. I know this part: `Failed to open \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi\` maybe related to various reasons so it is hard for me to find precise solution. Please, could anyone provide some newbie-friendly quick guide how to solve this issue... Provided there is one that does no include reinstalling OS.

Comment: I am familliar with that thread. Unfortunately I can not access recovery mode or my ubuntu terminal to apply proposed answer.

Comment: have a [look here first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode) then...  **0:-)**

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to run from an install media, do a chroot, reinstall grub. However, if your EFI partition is not corrupted (you have a dual boot, right?), then maybe running efibootmgr will be enough.

Your grub-install will look something like this (don't copy):

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Ubuntu
```

If the EFI entry is wrong (the "BOOT" part in the path looks like windows' efi boot), but the files are there, then you can create a new entry in your bios/setup/efi manager (choose desired name, select device, navigate to the right file).
If you want to do it from linux - use efibootmgr, something like (don't copy):

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdX -part NUM_OF_YOUR_ROOT_PARTITION -l /EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi -L Ubuntu
```

If your efi partition got corrupted - you'll have to recreate (create partition and format with FAT (e.g. mkfs.msdos)). Then you'd probably need to install the other os' boot manager and then ubuntu's.

And when done - you may create a backup of your partition table (with sgdisk).