# Unexpected return from initial read : Volume Corrupt , buffersize 5C00 . Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi : Volume corrupt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I was working with my Windows partition and when i finished , I wanted to go back to my Linux partition but when i restarted my Computer , There was no grub . Instead this error message has been displayed :

Unexpected return from initial read : Volume Corrupt , buffersize 5C00 . Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi : Volume corrupt.
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt.

Any solution to this problem please ... ?
I have so many important files in my Linux partition , that would be really BAAAAAD for me if they would be deleted ..
Thank you

Comment: This problem seems similar to another thread, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1071186



If thats not the case, the solutions in this thread should also be useful:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/906776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122261/unexpected-return-from-initial-read-volume-corrupt)

Answer (score 4):

First create a live USB of Ubuntu with a somewhat recent version. Then boot into the live-USB. When there, install boot repair by these commands given below in terminal. You will need Internet connection.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Then you will see boot repair automatically or you type `boot repair` in terminal. After a reboot it might work properly as before.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me i thought i had lost my filess.