# Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

So I turned on my computer this morning and instead of taking me to the dual boot screen to pick Ubuntu or Windows I got this error:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt 
buffersize 1000 Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubefi: Volume Corrupt  start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
```

and then windows booted automatically.
I explored askUbuntu and there are some similar cases however for them there are additional error messages that pop up followed by the blue screen of death. So, I didn't know if it would apply to me.
Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Windows, if you installed a driver to be able to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 disk partitions, then uninstall it asap, as it corrupts ext2/3/4 partitions.

---

**Lets quickly check your Ubuntu file system...**

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

- use fdisk to identify the EFI partition. It should be a FAT partition.
- `sudo fsck.fat -a /dev/XXXX`

**Update #2:**

Your EFI partition is not fixable by using fsck.fat. It's corrupt.

You can try using `Boot Repair`, instructions are found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), and it may or may not, be able to fix the problem. You'll need a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to proceed. Once booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, you may first wish to manually backup any important Ubuntu or Windows files to an external HDD.

Otherwise you may have a hard disk problem. You can use the `Disks` application to review the HDD's SMART data, and test the drive, for more info.

If that doesn't work, you'll either have to manually rebuild the EFI partition, or reinstall Ubuntu.

**Update #3:**

`Boot Repair` fixed the corrupted EFI partition, and the machine properly boots into Ubuntu again.

Comment: So I did this and after pass 5: checking group summary information, it says "/Dev/xxxx: 531335/12845056 files (0.8% contiguous), 8205372/51366912 blocks

Comment: furthermore, after the initial error, this error showed, almost the same with a little difference. Failed to open \EFI\UBUNTU\grubx64.efi - Volume corrupt. (next line) Failed to load image \EFI\UBUNTU\grubx64.efi: Volume Corrupt (next line) start_image() returned Volume Corrupt

Comment: @Excali please see Update #1 in my answer. Report back.

Comment: So I just ran this. This was the output: fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24) (next line) /EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi (next line) contains a free cluster (62). Assuming EOF. (Next line) /EFI/Ubuntu/grubx64.efi (next line) File system is 1105784 bytes, cluster chain length is 0 bytes. Truncating file to 0 bytes. (Next line) reclaiming 204 unused clusters (835584 bytes) in 1 chain. (Next line) performing changes. (Next line) /Dev/xxxx/198 files, 8115/65536 clusters

Comment: so after I ran your update, I rebooted and here is the error update: Invalid Image (nl) Failed to read header: Unsupported (nl) Failed to load image: unsupported (nl) Start_image () returned Unsupported

Comment: @Excali not good. You may have a hard disk problem. You can use the Disks application to review the HDD's SMART data, and test the drive, for more info. Please see my Update #2 for your next steps. If that doesn't work, you'll either have to manually rebuild the EFI partition, or reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: your third update worked!!. So i backed up a few important files and ran boot-repair through Ubuntu Live and upon reboot when I requested to launch Ubuntu, it worked and now I'm writing this on Ubuntu. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Excali great news! Thanks for the update.

Comment: I had the same exact problem. Worked after running Boot repair from the third update. Thank you very much

Comment: @AndreiBardyshev Glad it worked for you!

Comment: Hello @heynnema could you give a look to my question please? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264968/gnu-grub-boot-loader-failed-to-load-image

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with my dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows. In my case, that problem came out after an actualization of Windows that somehow corrupted my boot of Ubuntu. The solution for this headache is quite simple.

**Solution**:

*Note*: For this solution **USB memory** (pendrive) will be necessary. Recommended is an 8GB pendrive that is empty or ready to be formatted.

**Steps**:

1. It seems to me that in your case the Windows system is the first option to boot automatically if no option was clicked. In my case it was Ubuntu, that was corrupted, and my PC kept switching on and off over and over again. If this issue is happening with any person you can go out of that cycle by holding down <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd>, **depending on the version of your computer**. Then a "Boot Manager" will show up in the screen. Click on option to run Windows boot. If your Windows operating system is working well this step will lead you to Windows and once there you can work on it normally. Put the Pendrive on USB port.
2. Once in Windows, you can download the file at https://github.com/pbatard/rufus/releases/download/v3.11/rufus-3.11.exe. Open it and in the option "SELECT" you will select the .iso you need to download at https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.1/ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso. The last file is big and I recommend download it meanwhile the first one is downloading. For simplicity save both in the same folder.
3. **After select the image** .iso you downloaded, select the option **"GPT" on "Partion Scheme"**. Click on "Start" and follow the recommended options. This will create a image of Ubuntu in the pendrive.
4. **With the pendrive plugged in** restart your PC and again hold <kbd>F12</kbd> when iniciate. This time click in the new option that will pop up in "Boot Manager". This is the image of Ubuntu in your pendrive. It will initialize an empty version of Ubuntu and after that select your preferred language and click on "Try Ubuntu". A standard version of Ubuntu in now running from your Pendrive. **Connect with wifi** to repair the boot of Ubuntu in your PC.
5. Open a new terminal window and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair -y 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install boot-repair -y
sudo boot-repair
```

Then follow all the recommended options. Once this is done the boot of Ubuntu in your PC should be ready to work normally again.

6. Restart your computer and select the boot of Ubuntu in your PC. It may take a while but **everything should be fine by now :)**

**Observation**: If the pendrive is still plugged in when you restart your PC, a black window may show up asking you to remove your USB memory. Click enter. DONE!

Comment: Woke up this morning to the same issue.. I am running `boot-repair` at the time of writing. Thanks, Microsoft!

Comment: Another update, another day for `boot-reapair`. Wtf Microsoft?

Comment: Here we go again, thank you a lot Microsoft, I hate it.

Comment: thanks, guys. I almost lost a complete software project because of this!