# GNU GRUB boot loader - Failed to load image

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 20.04, windows-10, grub-efi

On 3 august I installed DiskGenius (and Ext2Fsd; I did not use it) to access to linux partition from windows and everything worked well.

Yesterday (5 august) I used Ubuntu 20.04 and after I turned off my laptop (on it there is the dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu 20.04). I turned on my PC, I selected the windows option from the boot loader GNU GRUB (as usual), then I used only firefox in Windows. Finally I turned off the PC.

Today, when I pushed the power button, the following message appeared:

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt, buffersize 0
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Volume Corrupt
start_image() returned Volume Corrupt
```

and then the Windows 10 OS starts.

How could I fix this problem? I tried to unistall both Ext2Fsd and DiskGenius but the situation remained unchanged.

P.S.: yesterday linux downloaded and installed the last updates before I turned off it.

Comment: You should run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). If it does not solve your problem automatically, please [edit] your question to include the Boot-Info URL generated by Boot-Repair.

Comment: Thank you very much @Melebius now it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already done, use `boot-repair` to recover from your corruption.

The Windows `Ext2Fsd` driver, used to read/write to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions, **WILL** corrupt partitions. Uninstall it asap.

If you wish to share files between Windows and Ubuntu, create a new NTFS disk partition to do so.

Let's check your file system for further corruption...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`