# Windows corrupting ubuntu EFI partition. How to recover and stop?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, uefi, windows-10

I use two separate SSDs to boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 with Ubuntu set as boot-first priority. Grub 2 takes care of the booting and it has been like this for 2+ years now. Recently after a Windows update, I'm noticing Windows not only messed up some of its own functions (time sync for example), but also the EFI partition of my Ubuntu disk was corrupted. It can't be a coincident. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu first time it happened. But today it happened again. I'm not willing to reinstall Ubuntu. Hoping I can **fix it somehow** and also **stop Windows from messing Ubuntu**. What should I do?
This is the error I'm getting during boot and then it skips Grub menu and directly boots Windows.

```
Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt 
buffersize 1000 Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi : Volume corrupt. start_image() returned Volume Corrupt.
```

I don't remember the exact error message to each words, but it read like the above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt,](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122261/unexpected-return-from-initial-read-volume-corrupt)

Comment: @karel partially. I also need to stop windows from messing it up in future.