# Login screen not coming up

Tags: boot, login, 18.10

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 on Dell Vostro Intel Core i3 7th Gen 14-inch Laptop (4GB RAM). The laptop had come with 16.04, which is now on 18.10 after 2 upgrades(18.04 and 18.10). Recently Bleachbit was performing some operations. System got hanged. After waiting for a long time I hard shut down the laptop. Post that upon restart, I'm getting the below message during boot and stops. Doesn't come to the UI login screen

My knowledge of Linux is very primitive.

Kindly suggest how to make it come to the logon screen and proceed further.

Is there an option in Ubuntu similar to Windows' Last Known Good Configuration?

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd. 
See 'systemcl status snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service' for details.
UBUNTU: clean 284707/60170240 files, 228632315/240659200 blocks
[OK] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.
```

Comment: Welcome! Try to switch to text tty (CTRL+ALT+F5), login using your credentials and try to enter the `systemctl status...` command which is being suggested to you. It may output crucial information.

Comment: @honza-kasik, When I try to switch to text tty, it didn't switch. It printed the below lines
`[ 250.221716] ACPI Error: Thread 2308353792 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 2104498048 (20180531/exmutex-382)

[ 250.221738] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66, AE_AML_NOT_OWNER (20180531/psparse-516)`

Comment: Try to access recovery mode instead (https://askubuntu.com/a/150377/362838) and then start the service using `systemctl start snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service`. After/if it fails, check the status.

Comment: @honza-kasik, I tried the steps mentioned in the link shared by you. 6 steps were through. 7th step, I see nothing coming up except a blinking cursor at the top-left of my screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found that <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> can help. Or to see where it is hanging use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>