# Cannot Boot Up After Crash During 18.04 Install

Tags: 18.04, updates, crash, reboot

I tried to upgrade to the new release last night and got a black screen about halfway through. That black screen was still showing this morning, so I did a hard reboot. I can now get no further than a screen whereat no inputs are possible.

I get a list of checks, each prefixed [ OK ]. The last one is ‘Starting GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service....ystem changes.pp link was shut down....’

I think I was running 16.01. The power was not conmected :( It’s a ThinkPad x230. Is it bricked?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to recovery mode (described in detail in another askubuntu thread:
[How do I boot into recovery mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode))
and then finish installing the packages by enabling network and entering root console.

If that fails, option is to boot from USB stick, and chroot into your laptop hard disk, and fix packages from there. chroot-ing is described on ubuntu docs:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery