# Boot Up / initialization of encrypted drive is stuck in a login loop after the battery died when upgrading the software

Tags: startup

My laptop is 256k pre-encrypted. I have been running Ubuntu on it for years with NO problems. I was upgrading the software when the battery died and it shut off. When I plugged it in, It would not start correctly. I now get to the log in window, put in my password after selecting User name that NOW has NO picture in it and it just continually seems to re-start, only to go back to the password window over and over and over. I was going to try a USB boot yet I have to get pass the Encryption also. How can I fix this without losing my data?

Comment: Does it seem to *reboot* (the part before the login page over and over), or does the *GUI Crash* (tries to start desktop after login, but then returns to login page)?

Comment: The GUI crashes and starts the Log-in page over and over again. For some reason, the GUI lacks the picture originally posted when I usually log-in also but I've tried other passwords and it quickly comes back to it faster than when I use my real password and it takes a minute before it comes back. Last night I tried to use a USB Boot that I created but quickly found out that A) I wasn't getting past my Encryption irregardless and B) I didn't want to re-install the program and lose all my data.

Comment: Can you boot to a [recovery console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode)? Try hard - if not, then your data is *already* lost. What do you mean by "My laptop is 256k pre-encrypted?"

Comment: YES! I got there. trying to find out regarding my data.

Comment: I ran the root and mount read/write. I ran the dpkg and fsck my filesystem is still read only though. By pre-enctypted, I mean that before I installed Linux, I encrypted the hard drive so that it must be password unencrypted before the O.S. loads.

Comment: My DATA is there and I can easily get to the recovery console but I cannot get any further. CAN ANYONE HELP? I'm very frustrated having attempted everything in the recovery console that seemed obvious.