# Failure to boot after installation ubuntu alongside windows on different disks

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, 20.04

**Description of the problem:**

Recently I tried to install Ubuntu alongside windows and after I finished with the installation windows doesn't boot correctly (power off option and advanced options only show up) and when trying to boot Ubuntu the PC is stuck on a black screen (GRUB doesn't even show up, to boot Ubuntu I changed the setting from the BIOS)

**Steps I followed:**

- First I reinstalled only Windows and where working fine.
- Then I created a partition on the second disk.
- I created a bootable USB with Rufus with Ubuntu 20.04.
- I changed some options on BIOS (think it was legacy support).
- I installed Ubuntu, keeping all the pre-selected options (including install alongside Windows--I didn't make a separate partition).
- When I restarted the computer before it shut down I forgot to take out the USB.

**Things I tried:**

- Messing with some options on BIOS (I don't remember exactly).
- Reinstalling Ubuntu with the option Erase Ubuntu LTS and reinstall (didn't erase the whole disk).

  After that when I restarted the PC (extracting the USB before shut down this time) the PC loaded grub, when I selected Ubuntu. The OS run smoothly but when I shut it down and restarted, the same issue was present.

Upon reinstalling Ubuntu with the same options, when GRUB loaded this time I selected Windows and the same issue a before was present with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You do not want legacy on, if Windows is UEFI. And if installing to a second drive, you need to use Something Else and either partition during install or partition in advance. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RZtSvkj2bT/

if understood correctly you were looking for this in order to help me?

Comment: HP often needs you to update UEFI & change boot order from within UEFI settings. The standard efibootmgr that works with everyone else does not seem to work with HP. You probably also need to add the BCD entry Boot-Repair suggests at end. You have both an Ubuntu and Windows UEFI boot entries, but neither are in the boot order? Can you manually select from UEFI? Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Secure boot and legacy support is off. In UEFI boot order USB hard disk is first then OS boot manager where Ubuntu is first

Comment: In OS boot manager do you have both Ubuntu & Windows. And do they boot or start to boot?

Comment: When I have Windows in boot priority windows boot but they run into a problem and a screen of shuting down or advanced options show up. Also 2hen I remove the second disc and windows boot only the same screen pops up. When I have Ubuntu in priority a black screen appears and they don't boot at all

Comment: @oldfred any ideas?

Comment: Windows repairs then is a separate issue. Grub only boots working Windows. Are you able to boot the recovery mode in grub menu. Second entry?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean

Comment: If UEFI you press Escape key to get grub menu at or near end of the UEFI/BIOS screen showing. If BIOS you press and hold shift key from BIOS menu.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/150367/how-do-i-boot-into-recovery-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end i saved all previous files
And deleted the disks and reinstalled **not with the option install alongside windows but i did a custom install**